# wait until a given time in UTC occurs in android

Tags: java, android, time, utc

I have a method which gets a given UTC time as a parameter.

I need to call another method at that UTC time mentioned. How can I achieve that in android.

Please help me with it.

Comment: Add some description and proper code to make able to understand the exact scenario that you want to implement.

Comment: Not needed. The question is clear i think.

Answer (score -1):

you can use  alarm clock  AlarmManager  and  BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Please elaborate how so that it can help OP, instead of one liners